# How do I store the initial state of a list of objects so that I can compare them to an updated list?

Tags: c#

I have a list that is constantly being updated throughout my program. I would like to be able to compare the initial count and final count of my list after every update. The following is just a sample code (the original code is too lengthy) but it sufficiently captures the problem.

```
class Bot
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        List<Bot> InitialList = new List<Bot>();
        List<Bot> FinalList = new List<Bot>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 12345; i++)
        {
            Bot b = new Bot() {ID = i};
            InitialList.Add(b);
        }

        FinalList = InitialList;

        for (int i = 0; i < 12345; i++)
        {
            Bot b = new Bot() {ID = i};
            FinalList.Add(b);
        }
        Console.Write($"Initial list has {InitialList.Count} bots");
        Console.Write($"Final list has {FinalList.Count} bots");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Initial list has 24690 bots 
Final list has 24690 bots
```

Expected for both lists to have 12345 bots.

What is correct way to copy the initial list so new set is not simply added to original?

Comment: Alternative as in "broken the same way" or "one that shows count 12345"?

Comment: `FinalList = InitialList;` same list (same reference). Maybe build a class that can save a `State`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you seem to want to do, you want to copy the list rather than assign a new reference to the same list. So instead of

```
FinalList = InitialList;
```

Use

```
FinalList.AddRange(InitialList);
```

Basically what you had was two variables both referring to the same list. This way you have two different lists, one with the initial values and one with new values.

That said, you could also just store the count if that's all you want to do.

```
int initialCount = InitialList.Count;
FinalList = InitialList;
```

Although there's now no longer a reason to copy from one to the other if you already have the data you need.

I get the feeling you actually want to do more than what's stated in the question though, so the correct approach may change depending on what you actually want to do.